# Problem: I could not inhibit a specific condtion

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I am trying this way:
I want to add some information if everything is ok.
But if one thing have missed out then i will not add anything
into the databases.

```
if(empty(username))//true
echo 'you must insert this username';
if(empty(password)//true
echo 'you must insert your password';
if(empty(headline)//true
echo 'you must add your headline';
//option for add some information
```

Problem i have faced now that is when my one condition is false
but it just perform the addition. How can i inhibit this. Please
help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I used to do it in my early stages of programming. Something like this could help:

```
$allConditions = 0;

if(empty($username)){
 echo 'you must insert this username';
}else{
 $allConditions++; //adds 1 to $allConditons, only if username not empty
}
if(empty($password)){
 echo 'you must insert your password';
}else{
 $allConditions++; //adds 1 to $allConditions, only if password not empty
}
if(empty($headline)){
 echo 'you must add your headline';
}else{
 $allConditions++; //adds 1 to $allConditions, only if headline not empty
}

if ($allConditions ==3){ // all previous checks passed
  // do something only logged in user could do
}
```

Later on, I realised, that if i reverse the logic, I am achieving still the same. Shortened:

```
$haveError = false;

if(empty($username)){
 $haveError = true;
 echo 'you must insert this username';
}

//...
if (!$haveError){
// all checks passed
// do something only logged in user could do
}
```